Update table via linq from viewmodel with list - ASP.NET Core MVC
I have a simple view model with list of items. If I try to update table from this list, I got error about conversion from System.Collections.GenericList to native model class (VykonyVykazyTmpModel). I understand this error, but I really don't know how I can accomplish my task.
My view model:
public class VykazyViewModel
{
    public VykazyModel VykazyModel { get; set; }
    public List<VykonyVykazyTmpModel> VykazyListModel { get; set; }
}

VykonyVykazyTmpModel is here:
public class VykonyVykazyTmpModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Uživatel")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} je povinná položka!")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Klient")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} je povinná položka!")]
    public int Vykon { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Výkon")]

    // etc....
}

And my controller
public IActionResult VykazKlientSave(VykazyViewModel vykaz)
{
    _db.Vykazy.Add(vykaz.VykazyModel); // it works
    _db.SaveChanges();

    _db.VykonyVykazyTmp.Update(vykaz.VykazyListModel); //here is the problem
    _db.SaveChanges();  
}

Thanks a lot

immediately after posting, I got solution. Mea culpa - not update, but updateRange ... sorry again

use context.Update for a single Item, and context.UpdateRange for a collection

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

immediately after posting, I got solution. Mea culpa - not update, but updateRange ... sorry again

That's not the solution at all. The actual solution is to only use Update on the root entity and only call SaveChanges once when you want to commit all pending changes. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. It detects all changes to the objects it tracks and persists all of them in a single database transaction. When you use Update or Add on a detached (ie untracked) object, DbContext starts tracking both that object and any other that can be reached. And since Id is autogenerated, it can decide automatically whether the object is Added or Modified

In other words, if VykazyViewModel was an entity you'd only have to call context.Update(vykaz); await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Thanx. But I need to first get key from new record, and after this I can save the collection. My code above is not complete.

Why do you need to get the key? EF fixes up generated keys on all related objects automatically
